# Canvas: Dividing Rectange in several sub-rectangles

Tags: android, android-canvas, polygon

This is a conceptual question, here it starts:
I am supposed to create, edit, save and resuse a CustomView which should be made of one parent Rectange and 12 inner-Rectanges/Polygons. I should be able to refer to each of them from code.

The easiest solution would be simple to draw 12 Rectangles, one next to each other, but it might be too heavy. What I was thinking about is to draw a huge Rectangle and divide it into parts (like for example polygons in GIS), but I did not find a single trace of such thing.
If anybody can suggest some light-weight concept I would be more than happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to the question -> at the end I have created every single erectangle separately, by extending RectF and modifyied a it a bit to get what I need. Since it is static and not having the performance issues I kept it.

Answer (score 0):

What about a general solution, where you model a rectangle like this:

```
data class Coord(val x: Float, val y: Float)

data class Rectangle(val topLeft: Coord, val bottomRight: Coord, val childRectangles: Collection<Rectangle>)
```

Then, you have a draw function like this:

```
fun draw(rectangle: Rectangle, canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
    canvas.drawRect(
            rectangle.topLeft.x,
            rectangle.topLeft.y,
            rectangle.bottomRight.x,
            rectangle.bottomRight.y,
            paint
    )

    rectangle.childRectangles.forEach { childRectangle ->
        draw(childRectangle, canvas, paint)
    }
}
```